# Custom Page Template Category loop not functioning correctly

Tags: categories, wp-query, page-template

So after several attempts to correct this - It seems the pages not load but don't pull in the correct posts from each category. It just seems to pull in the same default posts whenever I click each category link.

I've attempted to customise the query but with no luck here is the code I'm using below.

```
<?php global $up_options, $post, $paged, $wp_query; ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="bodywrapper">
        <?php $args = array(
            'title_li'           => __( '' ),
        ); ?>
        <div class="category-list"><?php wp_list_categories($args); ?></div>
    <div style="height: 25px"></div>

    <div id="content"> 
        <h1>Case Studies</h1>

  <?php

/* retrieves all the terms from the taxonomy portfolio */

$args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'category');

$categories = get_categories( $args );

/* pulls 5 posts from each of the individual categories */

foreach( $categories as $catergory ) {
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category' => $category->slug,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false
    );
}

$the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
    // the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                            <?php }?>
                        </a>
                        <h1 class="post-title"><a href="<?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lj_file_url', true) ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <div class="post-entry">
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lj_file_url', true) ?>" title="Download pdf <?php the_title(); ?>"> <img src="http://www.integra-av.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/pdflogo.png" alt="" class="alignleft"/></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                      <?php endwhile;

                       ?>

 <?php // Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <div class="clear">
                    <?php wpld_pagenavi(); ?>
                </div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 35px;"><span style="color: #2788e4;">Secure Solutions</span></span></p>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

here is a link to the current page I'm working on [here](http://www.integrabuildings.co.uk/index.php/case-studies/)

Comment: Why are you using a custom page template, rather than [relying on the Template Hierarchy to display the category archive index](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display)?

Comment: it is my category.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` is closed prematurely.

```
foreach( $categories as $catergory ) {

    // query args
    $args = array(
        // args
    );
}

// generate the loop
$the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );

// output the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    // Loop markup
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

You're saying:

1. Step through each of the categories; for each category, add query results to `$the_query`.
2. After stepping through the categories, output a loop for `$the_query`

So, you're only ever going to display the loop for the last category in `$categories`.

Instead, you need to put the loop output *inside* your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $categories as $catergory ) {

    // query args
    $args = array(
        // args
    );

    // generate the loop
    $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );

    // output the loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        // Loop markup
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

That way, you output a loop for *each* category, rather than just the *last* category.